# Data Table Row Insertion

Tags: c#, database, datatable, datarow

I would like to ask the method to insert the result of query as below :

which ID is the cusomter ID , num is the number of goods purchased , Product_x is the ID of the product

```
ID    num_0    Product_0      num_1    Product_1    num_2    Product_2  

1      3          435          2         122         1         236
1                 324                    232
1                 236
2      2          345          3         253         0          
2                 1519                   1563                  
2                                        79
```

The below is my following code

```
foreach (DataRow dr in tableShowDate.Rows)
{                
    String wo_number = handle(dr["ID"].ToString()) ;
    String date = handle(dr["DATE"].ToString());

    DataRow[] tempRowSelected = tempTable.Select("ID like '" + wo_number + "' ");
    DataRow [] originalRowSelected = tableOriginal.Select("ID like '" + wo_number + "' " + " and"+  " DATE = '" + date + "' " , "PRODUCT_ID ASC");

    for (int t = 0; t < tableOriginal.Rows.Count; t++)                 
    {             
        for (int x = 1; x < tempTable.Columns.Count; x++)
        {
            String compareDate = handle(tableOriginal.Rows[t]["CREATE_DATE"].ToString()); 
            if (compareDate == Days[x - 1])
            {                 
               tempRow["PHOTO_" + x.ToString()] = Convert.ToInt32(tableOriginal.Rows[t]["NUM"]);

               for (int s = 0; s < originalRowSelected.Length; s++) 
               {
                   tempRow["ID_" + x.ToString()] = httpLink  + Convert.ToString(tableOriginal.Rows[t]["Product_ID"]);
                   break;
               }
            }
        } 
    }                                
}
```

I would like to ask how to insert the row as shown in the table, given I have done the DataTable.select

the Below is my table

```
 Customer_ID   num    Product_ID      Date        

     1      3          435        2012-3-4         
     1      3          324        2012-3-4          
     1      3          236        2012-3-4
     1      2          122        2012-3-5
     1      2          232        2012-3-5 
     1      1          236        2012-3-6
     2      2          345        2012-3-4                        
     2      2          1519       2012-3-4                              
     2      3          253        2012-3-5
     2      3          1563       2012-3-5
     2      3           79        2012-3-5
```

Comment: That has to be the most original way *ever* of using markdown (fixed)

Comment: Your question shows 3 rows, all with the same ID... very unclear what you are trying to do here.